# <a href=“/statement.php?month=07&amp;year=2018”> need to Create two variables and pass into next reqst using JSR223 post processor

Tags: jmeter

[image: here is the screenshot of jsr223 postprocessor]Create  two variables assign month as one variable and year as another variable and pass into next request using JSR223 post processor am getting issue while doing this,can anyone please suggest me

Answer (score 0):

If your parent sampler response is `<a href=?/statement.php?month=07&amp;year=2018?>` and you want to extract the month and the year using [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) you can use the code like:

```
def response = prev.getResponseDataAsString()

log.info('Response: ' + response)

def matcher = response =~ "month=(\\d+).*year=(\\d+)"
if (matcher.find()) {
    vars.put('month', matcher.group(1))
    vars.put('year', matcher.group(2))
}

log.info('Detected month as ' + vars.get('month') + ' and year as ' + vars.get('year'))
```

Assuming everything goes well you should be able to refer month as `${month}` and year as `${year}` where required.

Demo:

[image: JMeter Demo]

More information:

- [Groovy Goodness: Matchers for Regular Expressions](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/09/groovy-goodness-matchers-for-regular.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: tq so much for ur valuable answer @Dmitri T